# Different between Query keywords Containing, IsContaining, Contains in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

What is different between Query keywords Containing, IsContaining, Contains in Spring Data ?

```
List<Movie> findByTitleContaining(String title);
List<Movie> findByTitleContains(String title);
List<Movie> findByTitleIsContaining(String title);
```

Comment: You can also, add the hibernate...show.sql=true to see theselect  sql statement generated  for both.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no difference, they mean the same [thing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords).